# What is the 'best' order for a list of items to minimising a cost function that is dependent on their order

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I'm trying to plan a work out with sit-ups/press ups etc. Each exercise will fatigue a muscle group by 'x' amount. After fatiguing a muscle, that muscle will recover (for simplicity linearly) at a rate of 'r' amount per second.

I want to order a set of exercises to minimise the maximum fatigue for any muscle at any point.

This feels like it may be similar to a standard problem which has been solved. Could you please point in this known problem?

[image]

Comment: If you want to minimise the maximum fatigue just don't work out XD. I think we need more parameters: how many muscle groups? can they overlap? Every muscle needs to be trained? I think that a greedy solution might work but I don't have the full image. Btw this is the correct stackexchange site :)

Comment: I've added an image with all the exercises on. Every exercise in the list needs to be completed. I'm interested in an optimal solution however I don't need one so you're right a greedy solution will probably do. Thanks

Comment: A greedy solution will result in an 'easier' workout at the start and will get harder, while it might be better to have the easier exercises after harder ones to ease recovery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we're talking about 14 exercises, the best option would probably be to use the [branch and bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound) method. Let's go through all the permutations recursively. If our current maximum is bigger than the upper bound estimate we had before, we should not continue this permutation, because it is guaranteed to be worse. If we calculated one full permutation, we should update the upper bound. The total number of states is
`14! = 8e10`, but a good number of them would be cut off.

It also helps to have a decent greedy solution to use as the initial estimate.

I'm also pretty sure that no polynomial solution exists because the function we're trying to optimize is too complicated.